# Vue reactivity listen from another object not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create a reactive `Vue` from another object. Please see below code.

```
test = {
    test: null
}

test.set = function () {
    this.test = 'data'
}

test_vue = new Vue({ data: test.test })
                   
console.log(test_vue.data) // null

test.set()

console.log(test_vue.data) // still null... I would expect 'data' here...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Vue 2's [`observable`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable) or Vue 3's [`reactive`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/basic-reactivity.html#reactive) to create a reactive object. For example, the following creates a data store that has a reactive `state` object:

```js
import { observable } from 'vue'

const test_vue = {
  state: observable({
    test: null
  }),
  setTest() {
    this.state.test = 'data'
  }
}

test_vue.setTest() // => state.test === 'data'
```

[Vue 2 demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/shared-reactive-object-in-vue-2-ryfbm?file=/src/store.js:52-74)

[Vue 3 demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/shared-reactive-object-in-vue-3-wyt5y?file=/src/store.js)

Answer (score 1):

Try to assign the `test` value as property and `set` function as vue method

```js
test = {
  test: null
}

test.set = function() {

  this.test = 'data'

}

test_vue = new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      test: test.test
    }
  },
  methods: {
    set: test.set
  }
})


console.log(test_vue.test)

test_vue.set()

console.log(test_vue.test)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: This would require me to set the values through the reactive dependent... not a very good design choice although it works.

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: A reactive flow from upstreams downstreams: calculate at test and test_vue will create a master dataset. Imagine that there are several upstream 'test' objects.

Comment: I don't understand your use case, but no matter what you want to do you could achieve that inside the Vue instance or any child component